# kun'yomi vs on'yomi

Tags: kanji, readings, onyomi

i'm just starting kanji , and a bit confused. if onyomi is when two kanji together why is　日曜日　 has both of the reading?when do i read the kanji kunyomi even so it's with another kanji?or do i just memorize them as words?

Comment: I'd say that it depends on frequency of usage for a specific reading. For instance, 車 is more often シャ than くるま... The only words I know where 車 is read as the latter are 車 and 歯車

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I have the right answer but in my view most *kun+on* compound words are kind of common "set expressions" like the days of the week, some time expressions, etc. I think in 日曜日 the last 日 "*bi*" acts more like a suffix, but I'm not quite certain.
My advice is, if you can, try to memorize the *kun+on*, *on+kun* or even *kun-kun* kanji compounds as words, not trying to read and split their meaning and reading because they are very few compared to the *onyomi* compounds and some are very commonly used. 
I hope it helps!